# Remove the first part of a string using sed

Tags: command-line, sed, text-processing

How do I get from this:

```
randomcollege-nt\user90
```

to this:

```
user90
```

using `sed`?

Comment: A helpful tip: when you are not sure what a command does, type in `man the_command_name` and you will get a helpful instruction manual for the command. You can also go to www.google.com and type in "command_name tutorial" and you will find plenty of step-by-side guides.

Comment: For tutorial on `sed` visit : http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Comment: You can also use grep for that: [How to remove a word prefix using grep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673287/how-to-remove-a-word-prefix-using-grep/562362733#56236273)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'd use a simple `grep` to look for `user90`:

```
$ echo "randomcollege-nt\user90" | grep -o user90
user90
```

If user90 is not constant, prefer this command:

```
$ echo "randomcollege-nt\user90" | grep -oP '(?<=randomcollege-nt\\)\w+'
user90
```

Finally using `sed` to edit the file in place:

```
$ sed -ri 's/randomcollege-nt\\(user[0-9]+)/\1/' my_file
```

Or to match all possible user accounts:

```
$ sed -ri 's/randomcollege-nt\\(\w+)/\1/' my_file
```

Comment: Funny thing is I tried that and it nothing returned. I'm using 12.04 if that matters. It only shows up if I `grep -F` the whole string.

Comment: @Roboman1723 tested on 12.04, my first commands works. Be sure that you don't have a grep alias defined somewhere. BTW as it seems you're looking for inline replacement with sed I've added such command.

Comment: Is there a way you could make that sed command cut out all "randomcollege-nt\" but display more than just user 90?

Example:
randomcollege-nt\user90
randomcollege-nt\user91
randomcollege-nt\user92

Output:
user90
user91
user92

Comment: @Roboman1723 You should attach your original file and your desired output to your question so that everyone willing to help you can see it.

Comment: @Roboman1723 Please check my updated answer

Comment: @SylvainPineau i think the first command is not an appropriate one.

Comment: @AvinashRaj can you be more specific about why it isn't appropriate?

Comment: OK. But, please, consider the case with brackets

Comment: echo '[Om/string' | grep -oP '(?<=[Om\\)\w+'

Answer (score 21):

You're parsing some text to extract the username from a `domain\username` string, most likely from Windows. Most of the above answers are only addressing your specific example string.

The best way to do this is using regex in sed to extract whatever comes after `\`. Here's how you would do it:

```
sed 's|.*\\\(.*\)|\1|'
```

That will match everything (`.*`) until a backslash (here, we're escaping it, so it's `\\`), then match everything after the backslash (`.*`), but making it a capture group (i.e. wrap brackets around it, but we also have to escape them, so `\(.*\)`). Now that we have whatever comes after the `\` in the string as a capture group, we print it by referencing it with `\1`.

You can use the above `sed` command with any domain name, not necessarily `randomcollege-nt`.

```
$ echo "randomcollege-nt\user90" | sed 's|.*\\\(.*\)|\1|'
user90

$ echo "domain\username" | sed 's|.*\\\(.*\)|\1|'
username

$ echo "anydomainname\roboman1723" | sed 's|.*\\\(.*\)|\1|'
roboman1723
```

Answer (score 12):

I know you want to use sed, but I'd use something different...

```
echo "randomcollege-nt\user90" | cut -d'\' -f2
```

Comment: Knowing *how* to use a tool is just as important as knowing *which* tool to use.

Answer (score 10):

Another `sed`:

```
$ echo "randomcollege-nt\user90" | LC_ALL=C sed -e 's/.*\\//'
user90
```

or POSIXly:

```
$ a='randomcollege-nt\user90'
$ printf '%s\n' "${a##*\\}"
user90
```

Comment: It's not a bashism, it's a POSIX `sh` feature. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02

Comment: +1. didn't see your answer, I'll remove my comment on OP's ^^

Answer (score 5):

Rather you use 'awk' to filter "user90":

```
echo "randomcollege-nt\user90" | awk -F\\ {'print $2'}
```

Comment: Is they're a way with awk to edit the file in place and not have to output it to a new file?

Comment: @Roboman1723 see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16531920/2072269

Comment: Yes you have to use -f option to awk.For details see man page.

Comment: Note that the argument to `-F` can be a regex, which allows for removing prefixes that match a pattern (and thus don't have to be exactly known strings). Also, when the input has multiple lines (commonly the case with a file), you can use `'NF > 1 {print $2}'` to avoid awk printing empty lines. For example, `awk -F "^Some Key *: " 'NF > 1 {print $2}'` will get you everything after lines starting with "Some Key    : " where the amount of spaces before the colon can vary.

Answer (score 5):

Is this the question ?

```
$ echo randomcollege-nt\user90| sed -e s,randomcollege-nt\,,
user90
```

if the sting randomcollege-nt is not contant use the awk commande above/below.

Comment: when I run that I get
`/user90` not `user90`

Comment: No that's alright,I got user90.

Answer (score 1):

This simple grep command will do the job,

```
$ echo 'randomcollege-nt\user90' | grep -oP '[^\\]*$'
user90
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sed` delete everything in a string before a specific character (define into double bracket [Specific char]).

```
echo "randomcollege-nt\user90" | sed 's/.*[\]//'
```

Means replace all (`.*[\]`) characters before a `\` char with whitespace character(`//`)

If you have a file and want to inplace replace use `-i` flag in `sed` command like this:

```
sed -i 's/.*[\]//' /path/to/FileName
```

Answer (score 1):

The original question asked for `sed`, but I see that alternatives are popular here.

If you are using Bash, parameter expansion is by far the simplest:

```
ORIGIN='randomcollege-nt\user90'
echo "${ORIGIN#*\\}"
```

If you are potentially expecting more than one backslash, double the hash signs:

```
echo "${ORIGIN##*\\}"
```

For more information, `man bash` and search for `Parameter Expansion`.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is trying to remove a commented out `# server_tokens off;` from nginx automatically to help with auto dev-ops:

`sudo sed -ri 's/#\s(server_tokens off;)/\1/' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

Tested and working for nginx/1.12.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Related answer to locking down NGINX by turning off server tokens [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33513698/1215344).

Answer (score -2):

```
echo 'randomcollege-nt\user90' | cut -f 2 -d '\'
```

Comment: this great answer of your has already been posted in Sept. 2014.