# How to arrange this file properly?

Tags: 12.04, bash, scripts

I'd prefer to edit TestFile in place to get the desired output. How could I do this? This is a work box so I'd prefer to not have to install additional packages.

TestFile:

```
randomcollege-nt\jsmith90
randomcollege-nt\aakhbar91
randomcollege-nt\pmanning92
randomcollege-nt\dvader93
jshephard94
bwayne95
```

Desired output:

```
jsmith90
aakhbar91
pmanning92
dvader93
jshephard94
bwayne95
```

Comment: Also visit : http://askubuntu.com/q/20414/256099

Comment: pff homework. try and solve it yourself

Comment: use `sed 's/.*[\]//' /path/to/fileName`

Comment: again ? http://askubuntu.com/questions/520080/remove-the-first-part-of-a-string-using-sed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -i~ 's/.*\\//' TestFile
```

- `-i~` tells `sed` to create a backup with the `~` extension.
- `s///` is substitution.
- `.*\\` means anything (`.*`) followed by a backslash
- the replacement part is empty `//`, i.e. everything up to a backslash will be replaced by nothing.

Comment: worked flawlessly, thanks. what's the "~" after "-i" do?

Comment: @Roboman1723 Please select as answer then

Comment: @Roboman1723, when you give the `-i` option an argument, it saves the original file with the suffix you provided. So you'll have the modified data in `TestFile` and the original data in `TestFile~`

Answer (score 3):

You can get output simply by using command **`cut`**:

```
cut -d '\' -f 2 < TestFile
```

Where `-d` is used to determine delimiter which is `/` here and `-f` for selecting fields which is `2` here.

Example:

```
$ cat TestFile
randomcollege-nt\jsmith90
randomcollege-nt\aakhbar91
randomcollege-nt\pmanning92
randomcollege-nt\dvader93
jshephard94
bwayne95

$ cut -d '\' -f 2 < TestFile
jsmith90
aakhbar91
pmanning92
dvader93
jshephard94
bwayne95
```

If you want to save output **to another file** then use:

```
cut -d '\' -f 2 < TestFile > Output
```

If you want to **overwrite** `TestFile` then use following command:

```
cut -d '\' -f 2 < TestFile|tee TestFile
```

Answer (score 2):

Though two correct answers have been given but I am giving my personal solution--

```
sed 's/randomcollege-nt\\//g' testfile
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

This is another solution using [**awk**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/awk.1posix.html):

```
 awk -F "\" '{print $(NF)}' testfile > outFile
```

where `-F` define the input field separator, than `print $(NF)` print out the last field.

`outFile` will contains:

```
jsmith90
aakhbar91
pmanning92
dvader93
jshephard94
bwayne95
```